# Creating anagrams of a word using a stack - when can we do it succesfully?

Tags: stack

Take a word A and an anagram of it, call it word B. We try to transform word A into word B by going left to right in A and pushing the character into a stack from left to right and, at any point, popping the character from the stack into the output word B.

For example, we have the word "insult" and want to make "sunlit." The operations

`push() (i), push() (in), push() (ins), pop()->s (in), push() (inu), pop()->u, pop()->n, push() (il), pop()->l, pop()->i, push() (t), pop()->t`

transforms this word successfully. However, this is not possible with all possible permutations of word A (indeed, I think the number of permutations we are able to realize is represented by the Catalan numbers, but I'm not sure). What property(ies) must word B have to ensure that this transformation is possible? Can we create an iff statement showing the class of all such words B? For simplification, it may help to first assume that the word is made up of unique letters.

Answer (score 1):

let's take source to be `abc` the possible permutations are `abc acb bac bca cab cba`

We can't get `cab`, let's try to figure out why.

- First character is `c`, therefore `c` must be on top of the stack,
  and anything preceding it in source either must have been printed already (therefore the stack is empty and `c` is the only element on the stack),
  or anything preceding it on source is on the stack. In this case `a` and `b` are on the stack.
- Second character is `a`, everything preceding it has been already
  printed or on stack? Yes, since there's nothing preceding it in source. Is
  it on top of the stack? No, since b is on top of the stack.

So we can say that a transformation is possible from source to destination if for every character in destination, it must be the top and only element on the stack, or anything preceding it in the source is present on the stack.

With this problem, I don't think you'll be able to do better than O(n) because every character will have to pushed and popped once. One can determine if a transformation is possible by simply doing it and see if the destination string can be reached.

```
public static boolean canTransform(String source, String destination) {
    if (source.length() != destination.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < source.length()) {
        stack.push(source.charAt(i));
        while (!stack.empty() && j < destination.length() && stack.peek() == destination.charAt(j)) {
            stack.pop();
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return stack.empty();
}
```

Hope this helps.